# INSERT SQL failing using Access with Azure linked tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, ms-access

I have linked several Azure tables to my Access 2010 front end. I can run SELECT and UPDATE queries without fail using the docmd.RunSQL *string* method, which is how all the code in this database was written. The INSERT queries are failing, as in nothing is inserted but no error is given. I've found very little on this on the web, but one site did mention i needed to list all fields (not just those with values) but that made no difference.

```
tableName = "userLog"
fields = "userId,machine,timeIn"
values = "'testUser','testMachine',#10/25/2016#"
SQL = "INSERT INTO " & tableName & " (" & fields & ") VALUES (" & values & ")"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

EDIT----

I tried entering the SQL string directly into the SSMS query window and it was returning an error related to the date field. So i changed it from
    #10/26/2016#
to
    '2016-10-26'
and that error was replaced with a new error stating:
    "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'LaborModel.dbo.userLog'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."
Does SQL not automatically add the unique value to the ID field? Clearly this is a difference between SQL (which im not familiar with) and Access operation.

Comment: I tried entering the SQL string directly into the SSMS query window and it was returning an error related to the date field. So i changed it from #10/26/2016# to '2016-10-26' and that error was replaced with a new error stating: 
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'LaborModel.dbo.userLog'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Does SQL not automatically add the unique value to the ID field? Clearly this is a difference between SQL (which im not familiar with) and Access operation.

Comment: Is "ID" the Primary Key? You can make it an identity column and let SQL generate the new key for you. Is the ID column an integer?

Comment: @DanielG Yes, ID is an integer and the unique column. Is that something i set within Azure's interface?

Comment: If you have no data in the table yet, you can do this from SSMS: 

Alter Table userLog Drop Column ID
GO
ALTER TABLE userLog ADD [ID] 
INT Identity (1,1)

Comment: Then make it the PK: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[userLog] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_userLog] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
     [ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: that did it. it doesnt look like any of the tables that were migrated have an index. Ill need to do this to every table. I cant mark your comment as an answer or i would.

Comment: no worries, glad you got it working. kindest regards...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have no data in the table yet, you can do this from SSMS: Alter Table userLog Drop Column ID GO ALTER TABLE userLog ADD [ID] INT Identity (1,1) –

Then make it the PK: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[userLog] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_userLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: See the edit question. I tried querying the DB from SSMS.